# Не могу ввести данные в консольную программу через subprocess

Tags: python, windows, консоль, subprocess

Подскажите, что делаю не так?
Задача запустить консольную программу, ввести в неё данные и подтвердить ввод. Последовательность скрипта:

> 1. Открывает dump\start.bat
> 2. Вводит данные -> Enter
> 3. Вводит данные -> Enter

*Пример моего кода:*

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen([r'G:\Documents\Python\auto_old_dump\dump\start.bat'], stdin=PIPE, text=True) as proc:

    proc.communicate(input='leZCsNCyp8fAIDh4-vMmf4mNCrSIOmqm0HJ4cODnsfK6bgjBfZ')
    proc.communicate(input='y')
```

так же пробовал `proc.communicate(input='y')` заменить на `proc.stdin.write('y')`

*Ошибка которую он выдает:*

```
C:\Users\barsi\dump>dotnet Dumper.dll 
Token: Auth...

Unhandled Exception: System.IO.IOException: ������ ���ਯ��
   at System.ConsolePal.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
   at System.ConsolePal.Clear()
   at System.Console.Clear()
   at Dumper.Program.Authorize() in C:\Users\bladee\source\Dumper\Dumper\Program.cs:line 33
   at Dumper.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\bladee\source\Dumper\Dumper\Program.cs:line 18
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\barsi\dump\auto_old_dump_3.py", line 48, in <module>
    proc.communicate('y')
  File "C:\Users\barsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1134, in communicate
    self._stdin_write(input)
  File "C:\Users\barsi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1083, in _stdin_write
    self.stdin.write(input)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

*Скриншот программы с которой взаимодействую*
[image: Скриншот программы с которой взаимодействую]

Comment: Нельзя вызывать communicate более одного раза. А для ввода символа переноса строки используйте `\n` которого в вашем коде сейчас нет

Comment: @andreymal Даже с один communicate код не срабатывает

Comment: Потестировал с простейшим батиком (2 ввода параметров типа `set /p a=[a]`) - не работает, второй ввод игнорируется (в консоли без питона батик работает нормально) . Написал простейшее консольное приложение на C++, два ввода отлично работают в том же однострочном питон-коде `subprocess.run('ss.exe', input="asd\nfgh\n", text=True)`. Вот вопрос, зачем нужен батик - может нужную прогу просто из питона вызвать?

Comment: Нашел способ! Если из файла читать, то батик работает; `subprocess.run('st.bat', stdin=open('in'))`. Но если батик несложный, то лучше все равно из питона нужную прогу вызвать...